# Panda how to groupby rows into different time buckets?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a dataframe with a datetime type column called timestamp, I want to split the dataframe into several dataframes based on timestamp the time part, each dataframe contains rows that value by its value modulo x minutes, where x is a variable.

Notice that `e` and `f` are not in original order.  With modulo 10 minutes, I want all times that end in `3` together, all times that end in `1` together, so on and so forth.

Group when x = 10

```
       timestampe            text
0  2016-08-11 12:01:00        a
1  2016-08-13 11:11:00        b
2  2016-08-09 11:13:00        c
3  2016-08-05 11:33:00        d
4  2016-08-19 11:27:00        e
5  2016-08-21 11:43:00        f
```

into

```
       timestampe            text
0  2016-08-11 12:01:00        a
1  2016-08-13 11:11:00        b

0  2016-08-09 11:13:00        c
1  2016-08-05 11:33:00        d
2  2016-08-21 11:43:00        f

0  2016-08-19 11:27:00        e
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39400830/2336654

Comment: I only want to split based on the time part. Need ignore the date part for the purpose of spliting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main tools will be `df.timestampe.dt.minute % 10` and `groupby`.
I used an `apply(pd.DataFrame.reset_index)` just as a convenience to illustrate

```
df.groupby(df.timestampe.dt.minute % 10).apply(pd.DataFrame.reset_index)
```

[image]

---

Just using the `groupby` could be advantageous as well

```
for name, group in df.groupby(df.timestampe.dt.minute % 10):
    print
    print(name)
    print(group)

1
           timestampe text
0 2016-08-11 12:01:00    a
1 2016-08-13 11:11:00    b

3
           timestampe text
2 2016-08-09 11:13:00    c
3 2016-08-05 11:33:00    d
5 2016-08-21 11:43:00    f

7
           timestampe text
4 2016-08-19 11:27:00    e
```